# how to generate values continuesly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, count

I have a function code like below

```
function setShort() {
var f = document.editFrm;
var x = 10;
//var project_company = f.project_parent..value;
//project_name from database, 76 = project_parent's id
if (f.project_name.value.length < 11) {
    x = f.project_name.value.length;
}
if (f.project_short_name.value.length >= 0 && f.project_parent.value == 76) {
    var w = 0;
    var y = "UKSP-LC-12-"+(w+1);
    f.project_short_name.value = y;

    return w = w+1;
    //f.project_short_name.value = project_company;
}
```

this function is for selectlist, which mean if the user click the `project_parent which id = 76`, it will show to another textfield which is `project_short_name`.

So how can i code it let `w` cannot be repeated to 0 but can continue `+1` after the first `0` saved, is it possible that use loop?

Or can i count the rows of the project parent so that i no need to use loop and just `w(total rows of project_parent from sql)+1`, im a newbie of loop and js, hope you guys have some ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `w` outside the function:

```
var w = 0;
function setShort() {
    // ...
    // remove line below:
    // var w = 0; 
    // ....
}
```

Comment: thanks alot man, this is work! now im trying another way but it is complicated too, i will post the question later. anyway thx